# Raw data size in elasticsearch index

Tags: elasticsearch

How can I calculate the raw data size that the index is based on? In the /${INDEX_NAME}/_stats I can see the total size of the index: the raw data and index structure. How can I check what's raw data size?

For example, I have a 1MB file with some documents. I indexed it to ES and the total index size is 1.3 MB. How can I do reverse engineering when I have the index size and I want to understand the raw data size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elasticsearch does not keep the source data size by default. But you can configure [Mapper Size Plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/current/mapper-size.html) to add the `_size` metadata field which keeps the size in bytes of the source data size.

When enabled, all documents indexed will have a new field '_size' defined with the length of `_source` document. For example:

```
GET my_index/_search?size=1&filter_path=hits.hits
```

Returns:

```json
{
  "hits" : {
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "my_index",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "123456789abcdef0",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_size" : 75,
        "_source" : {
          "@timestamp" : "2023-01-31T23:58:58.869Z",
          "content" : {
            "att1": "val1"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Moreover if you want to understand why the index size is 1.3 MB, you can use [index disk usage API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-disk-usage.html) exactly for this purpose:

```
POST my_index/_disk_usage?run_expensive_tasks=true
```